# Choose exact value in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking through a UCI Adult dataframe (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data). I want to output and count all the rows, where native country is 'Germany'. The following code:

```
df[df['native-country']=="Germany"]
```

Says me that all the rows are `False`. Is there any other way to count the amount of rows and/or print them out? Dummie might not be an option, since there are more than 20 different countries in the dataframe.

Comment: How are you reading this data? Seems like you should use `sep=', '` with an extra space at the end. Using just `,` will give you ` Germany` with an extra space before, and then your statement will yield only `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have white blank in the country field

Try

```
df[df['native-country']==" Germany"]
```

Or

```
df[df['native-country'].str.contains("Germany")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command `df[df['native-country']=="Germany"]` should already print only rows that match the condition. If you're seeing rows of `False` values, you might actually be executing `df['native-country']=="Germany"`, which returns a boolean mask of `True` and `False`.

To count the occurrences of each unique value in the `native-country` column, try:

```
df['native-country'].value_counts()
```